# Spring Boot JPA count query By Multiple Fields

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here down my code:

```
long contentCount = studentRepository.countBySubjectIdAndStudentTypeAndDepartmentIdIn(subjectId, studentType, departmentIds);
```

**Repository**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Student, String> {
      long countBySubjectIdAndStudentTypeAndDepartmentIdIn(String subjectId, String studentType, List<String> departmentIds);  
}
```

Here I have 8 records for subjectId I Passed and 8 records for studentType Passed here. But there are only 3 records for departmentIds I passed. But here this query returns 8 instead of 3.

Comment: where is your `@Query`

Comment: could you show us a scren shot of your data ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.